# How to find documents where a value is not in an array field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

In Mongoose, if a model M has this field:

```
list: {type:[String]}
```

How should I find a document in which a specific value x is not an element of 'list'? I am hoping there is a special operator '$ncontains' so that I can do the following:

```
M.findOne({list:{$ncontains:x}}...
```

Comment: For a "singular" value to match, MongoDB does not care if the data is in an array or not. Usually `$ne` will do. If you have a "list" of values you want to be "not" for either an array or a single value field, then use `$nin`

Comment: Wrote this many years ago. And people still get it wrong. [To $nin or not to $nin](https://snakierten96.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/to-nin-or-not-to-nin/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `$nin` (not in operator):

```
M.findOne({list: {$nin: ['A']}}
```

If you `$nin` array condition contains single element, you can optimize further by using `$ne` operator:

```
M.findOne({list: {$ne: 'A'}}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? The point is, list is an array but x is not. It is not the other way round.

Comment: Yes. it works. You can try it